# "Trying to get property of non-object" message when multiple users login in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm getting this error message while logging in. My login is OK. It redirects me where I want to, but when I put the wrong type it shows an error message. I highlighted the code on line 34 which generated the error message.

Error:

[image: error]

Model:

[image: model]

Controller:

[image: controller]

Comment: Okay fine, I solved this problem successfully. I changed the model in line 34. I write, **$db_password = $result->row('password');**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your model like that:

```
public function login_user($email, $password, $type)
{
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('type', $type);

    $result = $this->db->get('users');

    $db_password = $result->row('password');

    if(password_verify($password, $db_password))
    {
        // return $result->row(0)->id; #...not valid technically
        return $result->row(); // this is valid.
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

instead of this line: `return $result->row(0)->id;`

**write this line:** `return $result->row()`

> This will solve your problems, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Okay fine, I solved this problem successfully. I changed the model in line 34.

I write, **`$db_password = $result->row('password')`;** instade of ***`$db_password = $result->row()->password;`*** at line 34 in model.

Now my code works perfectly. Previously it showed **non-object** warning because I didn't call object in row() method.